# How to interpret symbolic formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On "Elements of Set Theory" 22p,

> For example,
>
> $$\exists x(x\in A\;\&\;\forall t(t\in x \Rightarrow(\lnot\, t\in A)))$$
> is a formula. In practice, however, we are likely to abbreviate it by something a little more readable, such as
> $$(\exists x\in A)(\forall t \in x)\;t\not\in A$$

I don't understand how the latter is equal to the former. The author introduced logical symbols $\exists$, $\forall$, $\in$, $\lnot$ and $\Rightarrow$. But regarding the latter experession there are empty spaces between $(\exists x\in A)$ and $(\forall t \in x)$, $(\forall t \in x)$ and $t\not\in A$. How should I interpret it? Below is my assumption.

1. $(\exists x\in A)(\forall t \in x)$ $\iff$ $(\exists x\in A)\land(\forall t \in x)$
2. $(\forall t \in x)\;t\not\in A$ $\iff$ $(\forall t \in x)\Rightarrow t\not\in A$
3. $(\exists x\in A)(\forall t \in x)\;t\not\in A$ $\iff$ $(\exists x\in A)\land((\forall t \in x)\Rightarrow t\not\in A)$ $\iff$ $\exists x(x\in A\;\&\;\forall t(t\in x \Rightarrow(\lnot\, t\in A)))$

If I am correct, 2 has a higher precedence than 1. Am I right?

Comment: You are confused. $\exists x\in A$ is NOT a formula.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Then is this $(\exists x\in A)(\forall t \in x)\;t\not\in A$ expression informal way to abbreviate the formula? Should I regard it intuitively and can't it be proved?

Comment: It's an abbreviation as the author says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation
$$(\exists x\in A)(\forall t \in x)\;t\not\in A$$
is *an abbreviation for*
$$\exists x(x\in A\land\forall t(t\in x \Rightarrow(\lnot\, t\in A)))$$
and symbol combinations such as $(\forall t\in x)$ *do not have any meaning* except for unfolding as such an abbreviation.

In particular, "$(\forall t \in x)$" **is not a formula**, and therefore it does not makes sense to write
$$(\exists x\in A)(\forall t \in x)\iff (\exists x\in A)\land(\forall t \in x)\tag{WRONG}$$
because you can't put the connective $\land$ between two things *that are not formulas*.

Writing $\forall t\in x$ *always* demands being *followed* by a formula that says what property it is you speak about all $t$ in $x$ having. That's just like the unabbreviated $\forall t$ itself.